# How to know if the user has scrolled to the end in an SWT Scrolled Bar?

Tags: java, swt

We have a case where we need to fire a server call to fetch next 100 records as soon as the user scrolls down to see the last element in a scroll bar. Please share any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ScrollBar` fires a `SelectionEvent` when it is changed. By listening to this event and comparing the scrollbar position + thumb size with the maximum size you should be able to tell when it is scrolled to its end.

```
final ScrollBar scrollBar = scrolledComposite.getHorizontalBar();
scrollBar.addSelectionListener( new SelectionAdapter() {
  public void widgetSelected( SelectionEvent event ) {
    if( scrollBar.getSelection() + scrollbar.getThumb() == scrollBar.getMaximum() ) {
      // spawn thread to fetch further data
    }
  }
} );
```

You likely want to refine the condition so that new data is fetched *before* the end of the scrollbar is reached, e.g.

```
if( scrollBar.getSelection() + scrollbar.getThumb() > scrollBar.getMaximum() - scrolledComposite.getClientArea().y ) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I was about to post the same answer earlier, when I realized that in the example I wrote, this doesn't work. `getSelection()` never reaches `getMaximum()` for a simple example with a vertical `ScrollBar` in a `ScrolledComposite`.

Comment: Baz has pointed out something which I wanted to. In my case, selection just reaches as much as 7 when I could see the end and scroll bar hitting the bottom peg. Maximum size was 20 in this case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. The `thumb' size needs to be added to the selection to match the maximum scroll range. I have changed the answer accordingly.